# Carregar dinamicamente link css externo

Tags: javascript, css, webp

Eu tenho 2 arquivos CSS externos que contém backgrounds da página.

Em 1 só tem links para imagens .webP e em outro somente .PNG , eu estou usando um script
para detectar se o browser aceita .webP e caso afirmativo ele altera o link CSS externo em HEAD
para o css externo com .webP, por padrão inicialmente ele aponta para o .png, testei numa página
mais simples e deu ok, mas na hora de colocar aonde quero não funcionou, segue o código:

No HEAD:

```
<link href="‪arquivos_css/png.css" rel="stylesheet" id="key">
```

No JS:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FUNÇÃO QUE CRIA O LINK EXTERNO CSS PARA INSERIR NO HEAD  //     OK//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
    function loadCSS(url){
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.setAttribute('href', url );
        link.setAttribute('rel', "stylesheet" );
        link.setAttribute('id', "key" );

        var para  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; //Nó pai HEAD
        var velho = document.getElementById('key');        //local exato do elemento a ser substituido

        para.replaceChild(link, velho);                      //Substituímos o velho pelo novo(link)
    }
//////////////////////////////
Chamada à função do webP
/////////////////////////////

WebpIsSupported(function(isSupported){
    if(isSupported){
       //CHAMA A FUNÇÃO LOADCSS e carrega o link CSS externo com WEBP
       loadCSS('arquivos_css/webp.css');
    }
}); 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
// FUNÇÃO QUE DETECTA A COMPATIBILIDADE DO BROWSER COM WEBP // 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function WebpIsSupported(callback){
    if(!window.createImageBitmap){
        callback(false);
        return;
    }
    var webpdata = 'data:image/webp;base64,UklGRiQAAABXRUJQVlA4IBgAAAAwAQCdASoCAAEAAQAcJaQAA3AA/v3AgAA=';
    fetch(webpdata).then(function(response){
        return response.blob();
    }).then(function(blob){
        createImageBitmap(blob).then(function(){
            callback(true);
        }, function(){
            callback(false);
        });
    });
}
```

O erro que está dando no chrome é esse:
Failed to load resource: *net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND*

Quem puder ajudar eu agradeço desde já !!

Comment: **net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND** Quer dizer que o arquivo não foi encontrado, veja se na função `loadCSS('arquivos_css/webp.css');` se você colocar `loadCSS('/arquivos_css/webp.css');` para buscar o arquivo na raiz...

Comment: Olá Daniel,

Eu tentei e nada, mesma coisa, até a url raiz c:/sistema/etc etc eu tentei e nada.

Comment: eu vou no elements e está lá no HEAD mas os arquivos não carregam e dá este erro no console.

Comment: Alguém pode ajudar ?

Comment: No console deve estar mostrando qual caminho ele está procurando o arquivo, da uma olhada pra ver se esse arquivo está realmente lá